# Python: pipe request to blueprint endpoint through another endpoint

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I have a Flask application that inherits a library with some blueprints already defined (that I can't change). Now I need to be able to filter out some of the requests that goes to one of the pre-defined endpoints.

The endpoint **/updateuser** is defined in the blueprint, but now I need to stop certain requests from getting to that endpoint, and instead return a message in my application.

I've figured out how to overwrite an endpoint in a blueprint, but that's not what I want. I'd like to add this **/updateuser** endpoint in my flask application, and either return a message OR send them to the original endpoint that's defined in the library, without the user being exposed to this extra layer.

Is there any good way to achieve this?

Comment: Couldn't you just call that function? I mean, the function related to the endpoint in that pre-defined blueprints.

Comment: The issue is that the request goes directly to the pre-defined /updateuser endpoint. I need to be able to intercept this request, since I can't change the logic in the actual endpoint.

Comment: I don't fully understand. You can add this endpoint into your application with your customized function and conditionally call that pre-defined function.